# What is the fastest connection between two MacBooks

Tags: network, thunderbolt, screen-sharing

What is the fastest way to connect two MacBooks? In my case I want to connect an MacBook Air (2011) with a Retina MacBookPro and use Screen Sharing.

Options I'm thinking of:

1. Thunderbolt/Ethernet and connecting both MacBooks directly?
2. something else?

Answer (score 4):

Direct wired connection is the fastest you can get, so go with Thunderbolt/Ethernet.

Comment: Not only is thunderbolt ethernet the lowest latency, it's also the highest bandwidth so it's a win-win.